# setup.py, pip - get origin path of execution of python package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have a python package that I need to install via `pip` as part of my project's requirements file, but I need to copy some files from my package to the projects installing this package. I'm thinking of doing it using the data_files option in `setup()` like:

```
setup(
    name='my_pacakge',
    ...
    data_files=[
        ('example/folder1', ['something1/file1.ext', 'something1/file2.ext']),
        ('folder2', ['something2/file1.ext', 'something2/file2.ext']),
    ]
)
```

and I woud like these files to be copied into paths relative to the directory where `pip install my_package` was run from, ideally my project root, leaving a tree as follows

```
project_root
├── example
│   └── folder1
│       ├── file1.ext
│       └── file2.ext
└── folder2
    ├── file1.ext
    └── file2.ext
```

but for this I will need to know the absolute path of where pip install my_package was run from. I've tried with `inspect.stack`, `inspect.currentframe`, `sys.get_frame`, `inspect.inspect.getouterframes(some_of_these_frames)` but this only gives me information about the current location of setup.py at installation time, which is directories like

```
/private/var/folders/gq/vpylvs0d51162jtyqhtgdc6m0000gn/T/pip-tNcbvb-build
/var/folders/gq/vpylvs0d51162jtyqhtgdc6m0000gn/T/pip-6a8MKS-build/setup.py
```

which is not useful at all for my purpose.

Now, I'm aware `setuptools`/`setup.py` should no be used like this but I really need to pack some files in the installable package and copy/move them to the project root at installation time.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you create this package, or is it something you downloaded and are now modifying. Second, what is the problem you are hoping to solve with this because this is definitely not the right way to do this.

Comment: I created it. I'm trying to build some sort of django-app "kickstarter" that will include a few reusable utilities as a django app for later use and I need to copy some files as part of this "kickstart" process. I'm aware this is not the best way to do it. I'm open to any kind of suggestions as long as this process can be triggered when I `pip install` my package.

Comment: I would recommend [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) which is better suited for this.

Comment: I didn't know about cookiecutter but it's amazing and just what I need!! If you want, go ahead and post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of trying to coerce setuptools to do your bootstrapping, consider tools like [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) which are designed to handle other bootstrapping and setup tasks for a variety of projects.

There are templates available for django as well (see [here](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) for example).

Answer (score 0):

## use `pkg_resources`

This package gets installed with setuptools.

From package docstring:

```
Docstring:
Package resource API
--------------------

A resource is a logical file contained within a package, or a logical
subdirectory thereof.  The package resource API expects resource names
to have their path parts separated with ``/``, *not* whatever the local
path separator is.  Do not use os.path operations to manipulate resource
names being passed into the API.

The package resource API is designed to work with normal filesystem packages,
.egg files, and unpacked .egg files.  It can also work in a limited way with
.zip files and with custom PEP 302 loaders that support the ``get_data()``
method.
```

In case, you install your package with `zip_safe = False`, your data will be available in directory.

Installing with `zip_safe = True`, it will be part of egg. But if you need to use the files from there, it is very easy and `pkg_resources` provides nice set of functions and methods

- pkg_resources.resource_exists
- pkg_resources.resource_isdir
- pkg_resources.resource_stream - provides file-like object
- pkg_resources.resource_filename
- pkg_resources.resource_listdir
- pkg_resources.resource_string

Note, that this works even for zipsafe True installations.

Just put your data into directory relative to your package direcotry. And then from your code:

```
import pkg_resources
fname = pkg_resources.resource_filename("your.package.name", "folder/example1.txt")
```

## use it only for statical files

Do not attempt to have there any files, which are changing. Technically it could be possible (with `zip_safe = False` the files are just there), but it is definitely bad design (permission, updates of packages).

## Do not init your project from `pip`, better provide some `appinit` command

Using `pip` to install your data into application directory is real abuse.

I would recommend to define a command installed by our program, like `appinit`, and use it whenever you need to populate your directory. Commands like `buildout` (installed by `zc.buildout`) and others are often using this patter.